# Select Case determines Exit code or run Update statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, case

Trying to get the select case statement to control whether nothing happens or a table is updated based on the sum of three fields from two different tables. One of the tables is a temp table (#tempGLsum). This holds the id field and the sum amount. The "amt" field in the tblPcardGL table should never go below 0 (zero). If it would, then the flow should stop. If it will still be > 0, then the next block of code would run, which updates the tblPcardGL table.

Any assistance would be appriciated!
Thanks

```
declare @glID int

create table #tempGLsum
    (glID  int, sumAmt decimal(18,2))

insert into #tempGLsum
    (glID, sumAmt)

        select      tblPcardReclass.glID,
                    sum(tblPcardReclass.reclassAmt)

        from tblPcardReclass

        where tblPcardReclass.glID = @glID

        group by tblPcardReclass.glID


select 
        case when (tblPcardGL.orgAmt - tblPcardGL.amt - #tempGLsum.sumAmt) < 0
            then 'stop here and let the user know it's below zero'
            else
            'run the code_below'
        end                         

from tblPcardGL

left outer join #tempGLsum ON
                tblPcardGL.glID = #tempGLsum.glID

where   tblPcardGL.glID = @glID
```

-- code_below

```
    update tblPcardGL
    set amt =
    (
    select 
            case (select COUNT(*) as numRecs from #tempGLsum)
                when 0 then
                    tblPcardGL.orgAmt 

                else
                    (tblPcardGL.orgAmt - #tempGLsum.sumAmt) 
            end
    )
    from tblPcardGL

    left outer join #tempGLsum ON
                    tblPcardGL.glID = #tempGLsum.glID

    where tblPcardGL.glID = @glID
```

Comment: A select statement doesn't "stop in the middle and execute some code below". That just isn't how this works at all. I think you need to try to explain more clearly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `if ( select case ... end ) = 42 begin ... end else begin ... end;`?

Comment: @SeanLange: Well, that is what I'm trying to do in the end. But if it doesn't work that way, that's fine. I'm open to working it any way. So, what I'm need done is when a user submits and adjustment to this record via a web page, the "remaining amount" (amt) field cannot be less than zero. The "original amount" dictates how much the adjustments can be. There can be several records of adjustments, which is why I sum them to begin with. Then I would like to evaluate the difference between the org amt less the existing amt. I am getting close with Brian Pressler 's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do what you want with a case statement.  You just have to do it in two steps:

First run the select with a where clause to show the user all the problems:

```
select tblPcardGL.*, 'Below Zero!' Error                
from tblPcardGL
left outer join #tempGLsum ON
                tblPcardGL.glID = #tempGLsum.glID
where   tblPcardGL.glID = @glID 
    and (tblPcardGL.orgAmt - tblPcardGL.amt - #tempGLsum.sumAmt) < 0
```

Then do the update with another where clause:

```
update tblPcardGL
set amt =
(
select 
        case (select COUNT(*) as numRecs from #tempGLsum)
            when 0 then
                tblPcardGL.orgAmt 
            else
                (tblPcardGL.orgAmt - #tempGLsum.sumAmt) 
        end
)
from tblPcardGL
left outer join #tempGLsum ON
                tblPcardGL.glID = #tempGLsum.glID
where tblPcardGL.glID = @glID
    and (tblPcardGL.orgAmt - tblPcardGL.amt - #tempGLsum.sumAmt) >= 0
```

You should consider wrapping all your `#tempGLsum.sumAmt` fields in `isnull(#tempGLsum.sumAmt,0)` because you used a `left join` so that column might evaluate to null, which will make any expression it is in become null.

Comment: Thanks for the example and feedback. I got it to work! Now I just need to learn how to "roll back" the last entry. And thanks for the isnull reminder!